# Elasticsearch: Find records where value is between two field values

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch (6.8) index with min and max values for a measurement.

The user inputs a value and I need to find records where the value is between the min and max fields.

Example documents in ElasticSearch:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "min_width": 125,
 "max_width": 215
},
{
 "id": 2,
 "min_width": 110,
 "max_width": 180
}

User inputs: 190

Result should return id 1 but not 2.
```

Pseudo query:

```
SELECT FROM my_index WHERE 190 BETWEEN min_width AND max_width
```

I can't use `range` queries because I won't have the min or max values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of two `range` queries, one for each field, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "min_width": {
              "lte": 190
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "max_width": {
              "gte": 190
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is going to return document 1.